# How many days the verification could take?

Tags: transactions, confirmations

I first time bought a smaller piece of bitcoin and wanted to do some shopping from that, but I still my wallet contains only not confirmed bitcoins.

My questions are:

1. Why the confirmation takes so long?
2. I saw a page that shows the total count of unconfirmed transactions, its increasing, not decreasing - could it mean that my transaction will never be confirmed?
3. How does the confirmation work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have paid a lower fee than others, so your transaction is put last. Your coins will return to your wallet, but can take up to 4-6 days before that happens. Hope it helps you.

Comment: Your transaction is put in something called mempool, from there it  goes to a block when one is created, the higher fee you pay, bigger chance your transaction will be confirmed.